# The definition of the quotient category in abelian category.

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I want to understand the definition of morphisms in this category. My question is how can I construct directed sets and direct systems, and therefore understanding the colimite.

Definition: Given a Serre subcategory $\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{A}$, the quotient category $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{C}$ of $\mathcal{A}$ with respect to $\mathcal{C}$ is defined as follows. The objects in $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{C}$ are the objects in $\mathcal{A}$. Given two objects $A,B$ in $\mathcal{A}$, there is for each pair of subobjects $A' \subset A$ and $B'\subset B$ and induced map $Hom_{\mathcal{A}}(A,B) \to Hom_{\mathcal{A}}(A',B/B')$. The pairs $(A',B')$ such that both $A/A'$ and $B'$ lie in $\mathcal{C}$ form a directed set, and one obtains a direct system of abelian groups $Hom_{\mathcal{A}}(A',B/B')$. We define
$$
Hom_{\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{C}} (A,B)= colim_{(A',B')} Hom_{\mathcal{A}}(A',B/B')
$$
and the composition of morphisms in $\mathcal{A}$ induces the composition in $\mathcal{A}/\mathcal{C}$.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We let $(A',B') \leq (A'',B'')$ when $A'' \subseteq A'$ and $B' \subseteq B''$. Then precomposing with $A'' \hookrightarrow A'$ and composing with $B/B' \twoheadrightarrow B/B''$ gives a homomorphism $\hom(A',B/B') \to \hom(A'',B/B'')$. Clearly this defines a diagram of abelian groups. It is directed, since $(A',B')$ and $(A'',B'')$ are dominated by $(A' \cap A'',B'+B'')$. Here, $B'+B'' \in C$ since it is a quotient of $B \oplus B' \in C$, and $A/(A' \cap A'') \in C$ since it is a quotient of $A/A' \in C$.

The construction of quotient categories can be found in Gabriel's thesis on abelian categories, or in any modern treatment of homological algebra, for example Weibel, Kashiwara-Schapira, etc.

Comment: Why $B′+B′′$ is a quotient of $B \bigoplus B′$? Thanks!

Comment: The sum of two subobjects $B' \subset B$ and $B'' \subset B$ is by definition in many texts from the image of the morphism $ B'' \oplus B' \to B$

Comment: Hi, maybe a silly point, but in case anyone else reads this and is confused: I didn't understand how $A/(A' \cap A'')$ is a quotient of $A/A'$; however, it does fit in the SES $$0 \rightarrow A''/(A' \cap A'') \rightarrow A/(A' \cap A'') \rightarrow A/A'' \rightarrow 0$$where the left and right lie in $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is the following case:
A/(A′∩A′′) is the subobject of A/A′⊕A/A′′, and the later is in C

Comment: What is the advantage to think the morphisms in a quotient category  in this way? Why not take the set of morphisms of the abelian category whose kernels and cokernels are in the Serre subcategory and use the left calculus of fractions?